# use replace to delete blank lines

Tags: python-3.x

```
a =""""94
 00:05

 The sun 
 It is a 

 95"""
a.replace("\n", " ")
print(a)
```

the output is:

```
94
 00:05

 The sun 
 It is a 

 95
```

But I want it to be:

```
 94
 00:05
 The sun 
 It is a 
 95
```

how can I do? I'm a new learner.

Comment: [Accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers if you feel it would be helpful for future users. For this use the tick near left top of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.replace("\n", " ")
```

The above code just return the modified line and doesn't modifies the string itself. So you need to reassign it to the original string to obtain the result. Just as follows :

```
a=a.replace("\n", " ")
```

And also there is a logical error in your code. It will generate output as :

94 00:05  The sun It is a  95

Because you are replacing every newline with space. So if you want your output as mentioned you need to replace two newlines with one and then remove spaces.

```
a=a.replace("\n\n", "\n") 
a=a.replace("", "")
```

So your code will be like :

```
a="""94
 00:05

 The sun
 It is a

 95"""
a=a.replace("\n\n", "\n")
a=a.replace(" ", "")
print(a)
```